# C-DLL to be used by MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Since MATLAB is not good with loop, I am putting some of the looping into a c-dll(visual studio 6.0).

- What do I have to do in building the c-dll that is different than
  normal dlls?
- How do I interface with the DLL from MATLAB?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? MATLAB is not that bad at loops anymore. Apart from relying on MATLAB's JIT have a look at *vectorization*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend making them into MEX-functions. Read the MATLAB help: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29322.html.

And FWIW, MATLAB's fine at looping if you write your code well.